# Keep running into: bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sed'

Tags: bash, if-statement

I'm a computational biologist learning how to use AMBER to run molecular dynamics simulation. I am new to Linux operation, but I couldn't find the solution to the following problem.

When I copy and paste the "README" script obtained from CHARMM-GUI input file generator, the following error appears:

```
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `sed'
```

I believe the syntax error is occuring on this line:

```
if (-e "dihe.restraint") sed -e "s/FC/1.0/g" dihe.restraint > ${mini_prefix}.rest
```

Similarly, I run into a similar issue in later scripts:

```
if ( ${cnt} == 1 ) set pstep = ${equi_prefix}

bash: syntax error near unexpected token `set'
```

Sincerely,

Comment: Looks like that might be C Shell conditional syntax, but you're running it in bash.

Comment: Please try the following substituting the UPERCASE parameters suronded by <>,  `if [  <CONDITION>  ] ; then <SED_COMMAND_HERE> ;fi`